# Ionic Firebase Test Lab - Robo Test

Tags: android, firebase, testing, ionic-framework, firebase-test-lab

I have googled everything so far, but I couldn’t find anything how to record a Robo Test of you Android Ionic application. With the recorded test I can submit it to Firebase Test Lab to run it over multiple devices.

I came this far:

- I opened my project in Android Studio
- I opened Test Lab settings via Tools > Firebase > Test Lab
- Then when I try to record a Robo script, it shows only one event: ‘Delay 60000 milliseconds’

Does anyone have a clue on how to do this?

Answer (score 1):

Test Lab currently only supports native Android apps.  Other frameworks, such as Ionic, are not supported.